# How to float div to the left when min-width has been reached?

Tags: html, css

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="subsSection">
       <div class="leftSection">ss</div>
       <div class="rightSection">ss</div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

(1) I want the subsection div, to be centered on the screen. but when its min-width have been reach on re size, then float to the left and no longer be centered. this is to use the left margin space.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rayabu1234/14cnypyy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use media query for this

**css**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    #subsSection{
        width:20%;
        float:left;        
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, with the help of jquery, you can achieve the same by finding the device width!!